# MSXML always adding Namespace to Elements

Tags: xml, vba, msxml

I want to create an XML using MSXML in VBA.
The target output is pretty basic:

```
<Main xmlns="http://www.myurl.com/xml">
    <Info>
        <BaseData>
            <CreationDate>2021-11-10</CreationDate>
            <Hardware>
                <Frquency>100</Frquency>
            </Hardware>
            <SomeCode>000000_0000000</SomeCode>
            <SomeName>HW GPU SoC 1</SomeName>
        </BaseData>
    </Info>
</Main>
```

However my code is generating an **xmlns** attribute in the "Info" element and I don't know why:

```
 <Main xmlns="http://www.myurl.com/xml">
    <Info xmlns="">
        <BaseData>
            <CreationDate>2021-11-10</CreationDate>
            <Hardware>
                <Frquency>100</Frquency>
            </Hardware>
            <SomeCode>000000_0000000</SomeCode>
            <SomeName>HW GPU SoC 1</SomeName>
        </BaseData>
    </Info>
</Main>
```

Here is the code:

```
Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim root As IXMLDOMNode
   
Dim info As IXMLDOMElement, baseData As IXMLDOMElement
Dim someCode As IXMLDOMElement, someName As IXMLDOMElement, hardware As IXMLDOMElement, freq As IXMLDOMElement, creationDate As IXMLDOMElement
       
Dim namesp As String
  
namesp = "http://www.myurl.com/xml"
Set root = doc.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "Main", namesp)
doc.appendChild root

          
Set info = doc.createElement("Info")
Set baseData = doc.createElement("BaseData")
Set someCode = doc.createElement("SomeCode")
Set someName = doc.createElement("SomeName")
Set hardware = doc.createElement("Hardware")
Set freq = doc.createElement("Frquency")
Set creationDate = doc.createElement("CreationDate")

freq.Text = "100"
hardware.appendChild freq

creationDate.Text = "2021-11-10"
someCode.Text = "000000_0000000"
someName.Text = "HW GPU SoC 1"

baseData.appendChild creationDate
baseData.appendChild hardware
baseData.appendChild someCode
baseData.appendChild someName
  
info.appendChild baseData

root.appendChild info
doc.Save (filePath)
```

When I change the line to "Set info = doc.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "Info", namesp)" the xmlns attribute moves to BaseData. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your target output all the elements belong to the http://www.myurl.com/xml namespace. They inherit the namespace from your root element.

You only create your root element with this namespace. All other elements have an empty namespace. That is why the namespace gets reset to an empty namespace in your first child.

To get your target xml output, create ALL elements using your namespace.
e.g. use

```
Set info = doc.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "Info", namesp)
```